# For loop runs only once when using modulus inside if-else in C

Tags: c, loops, modulo

```
/*This is a c program I made to print prime numbers between 0 and n,
  the loop in this program runs once and terminates.*/

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the value of n\n");
    
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int c = 0;
         
        for (j = 0; j <= i / 2; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
            { 
                c++;
            }
        }
        
        if (c == 1)
        {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output of the program:

```
Enter the value of n
10


...Program finished with exit code 0
Press ENTER to exit console.
```

Comment: `break;` Do you know what that statement does in C? Also, what did you expect the code to do instead? The loop is supposed to exit once it finds that the number is not a prime. Seems to be working so it's not clear what you think it should do instead.

Comment: So what is the problem? The output is correct i.e. 50 is not a prime. Whne 50%2 == 0 it is breaking the loop.

Comment: You only need to find one non-prime, so the `break` is correct.

Comment: Hang on, you've just replaced the whole code. Please be clear as to what you are asking.

Comment: Where is the original code?

Comment: Sorry I pasted the wrong code earlier

Comment: `if(c==1)`  Under what conditions do you expect `c` to be 1 considering `c++` is used to change it? Do basic debugging - step thru the code or add more debug print statements to trace the execution and variable values.

Comment: You need to break after `c++;`

Comment: Please note that when your codes ends up evaluating `0 % 0` it invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

/*This is a c program I made to print prime numbers between 0 and n,
the loop in this program runs once and terminates.*/

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the value of n\n");
    
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        int c=0;
        
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0)
            {
                c++;
            }
        }
        
        if(c==1)
        {
            printf("%d\n",i);
        }
    }
}
```

The use of second for loop is to find that  no. is prime or not and to prove that you have to check two possibilities, that is should be divisible by one and by istself. so, you have to initialize `if(c==2)` ,`j=1` and `j<=i`.